# Method that creates new object of the same type, replaces initial object with the new one

Tags: c#, .net

i know that .NET String class uses such behaviour, but I can't find any implementation, and i don't know how to name this behaviour. Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string class is referred to as being [Immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable).

An extremely simplified example might look like:

```
public sealed class MyValue
{
  public MyValue(int value)
  {
    this.Value = value;
  } 

  public int Value { get; private set }

  public MyValue Add(int value)
  {
    return new MyValue(this.Value + value);
  }
}
```

The object in this context cannot be changed.  If you require another MyValue object with the current value added to another value, you get a new object.

Comment: I know this, but in Wikipedia article i didn't found any approach to implemetation of such methods for immutable objects. How could i replace initial object with new created within method? Should i use pointers?